# loading of fasttext pre trained german word embedding's .vec file throwing out of memory error

Tags: nlp, gensim, word-embedding, fasttext

I am using gensim to load the fasttext's pre-trained word embedding

`de_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('wiki.de\wiki.de.vec')`

But this gives me a memory error.

Is there any way I can load it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than working on a machine with more memory, the `gensim` `load_word2vec_format()` methods have a `limit` option which can be given a count *n* of vectors to read. Only the first *n* vectors of the file will be loaded.

For example, to load just the 1st 100,000 words:

```
de_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('wiki.de\wiki.de.vec', limit=100000)
```

Since such files usually sort the more-frequent words first, and the 'long tail' of rarer words tend to be weaker vectors, many applications don't lose too much power by discarding rarer words.